# ¿Cómo reproducir simultáneamente dos archivos en vlc?

Tags: consola

Quiero reproducir dos archivos simultáneamente en vlc. Desde la interfaz gráfica, es fácil, pero, ¿cuáles serían los parámetros que debo usar si quiero ejecutar vlc desde la consola, reproduciendo los dos archivos simultáneamente?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795289/3590533

Comment: Mas bien, preguntaba por qué parámetro adicional debía usar para que los dos archivos se reproduzcan simultáneamente.

Comment: Tal vez puedas dar un ejemplo de lo que quieres conseguir, se pueden interpretar muchas cosas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solucion seria ejecutar VLC varias veces en una sola linea, por ejemplo, con el comando `vlc 1.wav` reproduciras el archivo 1.wav con VLC, pero (dependiendo del sistema operativo) podrias ejecutar multiples veces el programa VLC.

**En Windows**

La forma de ejecutar varias instrucciones en el CMD de Windows en una sola linea es con el simbolo `&`, por lo  tanto con el comando: `vlc 1.wav & vlc 2.wav... & vlc n.wav` reproduciras los `n` archivos.

**En Linux**

Aqui se usa el mismo simbolo `&`, pero en Linux este simbolo tiene un significado distinto, ya que lo que hace es ejecutar el siguiente comando de forma asyncronica en una sub-terminal, por lo que en este caso habria un pequeño desfase.

Yo lo hice asi y me funciono en Windows 10:

[image: VLC]

Comment: He probado la versión para Linux y no las abre simultáneamente sino que espera que una acabe para abrir la otra.

Comment: Tienes razon, ya modifique mi respuesta, la unica solucion que encontre seria usando `&` tambien, pero en Linux usar `&` hace que se ejecuten varias instrucciones de forma asincronica, por lo que habria un pequeño desfase, lo probe en Fedora 25 y pude abrir 2 videos, pero como un desfase de `0.1` o `0.2` segundos.